# Fit realtime text inside container

Tags: javascript, css, text, angular

I am using Angular 2 with (for now) 2 way data binding and I need to diplay a H1  over the full width of the page. So it will become smaller the more text there will be. And bigger if the amount of text shrinks.

I saw http://fittextjs.com but that resizes it only on the page init.

I need it in realtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this

https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill

And you can call them when you want (after text render), simply, calling

```
$('#my-element').textfill({
        maxFontPixels: 36
    });
```

And it's very customizable.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: It doesn't resize the text. I am using a 2 way binding so it's rendered on the DOM. It's using {{Sentence}}. It doesn't resize at all.

Comment: Try launching via console when the DOM is totally rendered, so you can see if the problem is the plugin or another thing

Comment: Each time I run it, it gets bigger, and it doesn't change when the text changes

Comment: It doesn't change when the text changes. It calculates, based on text lenght, and container size, the optimal size. If you change your text, you should call textfill programatically

Comment: Okay, so then 2 questions: 1. How can I call textfill then? 2. Why is it really small if I use textfill? I want it to be the width of a container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103510/discussion-between-anned20-and-del).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I understand the problem now replace px with whatever unit of length

```
<h1 ng-style="{'max-width':'100%', 'font-size':  inputlength + 'px'}">{{input}}</h1>
```

You may have to tweak it to however you want to get it to work
essentially having to do the logic like  font-size:calc(100% + 2vw)
or work it out in your controller

```
 $scope.input = "ssssssss";
               $scope.inputlength = 10;
                $scope.$watch('input', function(){
                     $scope.inputlength = window.innerWidth / $scope.input.length;
                });
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It just remains the original H1 size

Comment: It's double bracket `{{data}}`

Comment: Have you tried making the h1 to a div?  perhaps you have a global h1 setting in your css file?

Comment: Jup, I did and I don't have any H1 settings

Comment: `ng-style`? `input.length/20+'px'`?

Comment: oops sorry i have been drowsy

Comment: It still doesn't work :/

Comment: It works now but you have to work out the logic for font size, i.e (input.length/100)

Comment: Still doesn't work. This is the compiled output: `<h1 ng-style="{'max-width':'100%', 'font-size':  (Sentence.length/10)}">Hello World</h1>`

Comment: (input.length/100)+ 'px'   - you forgot to add the unit of measurement? px or vw or em or whatever

Comment: Does nothing. It stays the same.

Comment: This definitely works - check the code add the js and try it - I just edited the answer

Comment: If this doesnt work then i'm sure your controller is not having scope to your template